# How to use instance_spy to debug unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I have a unit test with the following that I'm trying to debug:

```
describe "#issue!" do
  it "delegates to task#issue" do
    t = instance_spy("Task")
    expect(t).to receive(:issue).with(type: 'create_task')
  end
end
```

the method it's hitting is coming from this:

```
def issue!
  t = object.tasks.new
  t.issue(type: 'create_task')
  t
end
```

and when I run rspec I get the following message:

> Failure/Error: expect(t).to receive(:issue).with(type: 'create_task')
>         (InstanceDouble(Task) (anonymous)).issue({:type=>"create_task"})
>             expected: 1 time with arguments: ({:type=>"create_task"})
>             received: 0 times

Basically, I want to know how does the instance_spy work? Does it create a new object that bypass validation without saving it to the database similar to using .new or does it save it to the database without going through validation (.create!(validate: false))?  Been trying to troubleshoot this error for a while now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your spec you never actually call anything after the `expect` which would invoke `issue!`. Remember that after the spec, any spies and mocks will be uninstalled.

Besides that, `instance_double` creates a new dummy object which resembles the specified class in that the same methods present on instances of the original class can be called on it.

It's called [verifying double](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/tree/master/features/verifying_doubles) and also documented in the [documentation of `rspec-mocks`](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks).